How to use Selenium to run multiple path_profiles at once?
I encountered an issue when using Selenium for web automation. The path_profile is not working properly; it needs to be set as default first.
I have tried several options, including ensuring the Firefox window is properly closed and using taskkill on firefox.exe, because from the information I have gathered, this needs to be done to avoid detection of duplication in Firefox, but this method did not work. Does anyone know a solution for this?
